# Ansible assign items to variable using with_items

Tags: list, loops, dictionary, ansible, variable-assignment

I'm using a PM2 role from Ansible Galaxy. The role looks like this:

```
roles:
  - role: weareinteractive.pm2
    vars:
      pm2_apps:
        - run: pm2.json
          path: "{{ project_root }}/auth"
          cmd: startOrGracefulReload
        - run: pm2.json
          path: "{{ project_root }}/graphql"
          cmd ...

          etc..
```

Under pm2_apps, I can assign multiple modules to be run. How can I populate this structure with the following items:

```
app_modules:
- { module: "auth", "run": 1 }, 
- { module: "graphql", "run": 2 }, 
- { module: "upload", "run": 3 }
```

I only want to change the path of pm2_apps to:

```
path: "{{ project_root }}/{{ item.module }}"
```

Among many things, I tried:

```
pm2_apps:
  - run: pm2.json
    path: "{{ project_root }}/{{ item.module }}"
    cmd: startOrGracefulReload
    with_items: "{{ app_modules }}"
```

Since it's a role, I don't want to rewrite its tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `pm2_apps` is a var, not an action, I'm pretty sure you just need to generate that structure using either a `for` loop or some of jinja's `map` and `combine` toys:

```
vars:
  app_modules:
  - { module: "auth", "run": 1 }
  # **definitely** don't put the trailing comma like you have in your question

  pm2_apps: |
    {% set results = [] %}
    {% for am in app_modules %}
    {%   set it = am | combine({"cmd": "startOrGracefulReload"}) %}
    {%   set _ = it.update({"path": project_root + "/" + it.module}) %}
    {%   set _ = results.append(it) %}
    {% endfor %}
    {{ results }}
```